# Can an iOS device using some app connect with another iOS device over bluetooth if the 2nd device doesn't have the app?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am relatively new to bluetooth tech. and find it really fascinating.

I would like to know the possibilities of achieving the following:

1. A(has some app) -> B(Doesn't have the app)
2. A(doesn't have the app) -> B(Doesn't have the app)

If the 2nd scenario is possible then is it possible to achieve communication between the two paired devices?

If first one is the possibility then how could you design the UX for it?

Thank you in advancce

Comment: Unfortunately I believe your question is far too broad to merit a proper answer.  However I think you 'might' be talking about creating a PAN between two bluetooth devices.  I believe however that both devices must have the app in order to communicate properly, otherwise the only thing you can do with the device that doesn't have the app is go into 'discovery' mode whereby the phone is looking for *other* bluetooth devices to pair with.  Discovery mode doesn't really allow for data transfer in the way I believe you want to achieve. 

Short answer: no for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if your intention is to discover available devices in scenario 1 then yes it is possible and you'll find a lot of demos on github so it's not hard.

But for data transfer it isn't possible to do that unless your app coordinates the communication between them.

Comment: Thanks.. Ahmed. That explained the scenario quite subtly.. :)